# How to bind/pair a Sunvic wireless radio heating controller to its receiver

Tags: heating, central-heating, home-automation

I have a Sunvic wireless controller and thermostat with a receiver base station in the boiler room. It became detached and I'd like to reconnect it with the controller unit.

Note: this is a question I know the answer to but I couldn't find it on the web, so I'm putting it here and intend to answer my own question. I don't think this site lets you answer your own for a few hours, so **I'm going to stick the answer right here**.

1/ Grab that handy paperclip you keep for poking and hooking things.

2/ Hold the On Off button on the receiver for 3 seconds or until the green LED flashes.

3/ On the back of the controller, with your paperclip, press/poke the Learn button.

Note that the Red LED means 'working' while the Green LED means 'you're going to freeze in your own house'. This might be something to do with Chinese manufacturing and red being their most positive colour.

Comment: You can answer your own question, just update your question to be just the question and then add your answer.  You can even mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Grab that handy paperclip you keep for poking and hooking things.

2/ Hold the On Off button on the receiver for 3 seconds or until the green LED flashes.

3/ On the back of the controller, with your paperclip, press/poke the Learn button.

Note that the Red LED means 'working' while the Green LED means 'you're going to freeze in your own house'. This might be something to do with Chinese manufacturing and red being their most positive colour.